# Vim - E488 error - Trailing characters in search and replace command

Tags: regex, linux, unix, vim

The instructions say to: "Write a command that will change all "-" characters to "/" characters in every line that begins with an "F" or a "C" character."

I tried this in Vim but I'm getting E488: Trailing characters.
Any suggestions? Thanks.

```
:%s/^\(F|C\)/\-/\//g
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
:g/^[FC]/s/\-/\//gc
```

Explanation:

```
^[FC]: Do replacements only in those lines which start with F or C.
\-: Look for -
\/: Replace with /
gc: Do the replacements interactively. (Change it to g for non-interactive mode).
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. It seems that I was putting the ^ part after the s.

Comment: that is the same solution as the one provided by me. BTW: you don't need to escape the `-`.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I thought I would give an answer which will work just by copy-pasting. Yes, credit goes to you.

Answer (score 4):

The traditional way of doing *do in all lines matching* in Vi is to use a `:g` command. So in your case, this would be:

```
g/^[FG]/s#-#/#g
```

Which means, do a substitute command on all lines that start with either a `F` or a `G`. Note, since you want to use the `/` as replacement char, I have been using a different delimiter `#`.

Comment: What is the difference between `%s` and `g`?

Comment: Have you looked at the help? `:h :s` and `:h :g` If there is anything unclear, please say so

Answer (score 2):

If you need to use a slash in your match or replacement, it's best to use another character as your separator -- a comma will do: `%s,/,-,g`

Here, you also need to use a positive look-behind assertion:  Replace any dash that's preceded by anything that begins with F or C, with a slash.  In vim, this is written using `\@<=`

`:%s,\(^[FC].*\)\@<=-,/,g`

More information: [:help pattern](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/@%3C=)